# How to set up a local DBPedia Server and using it

Tags: node.js, rdf, sparql, dbpedia

I am wondering if there is a tutorial on how i could get a local copy of the dbpedia knowledge base up and running.

I understand that i'll have to download all the .nt files that i would like to include from the dbpedia website. But i don't really get how to utilize them.

From other questions i found out, that there are different interfaces of different languages for using this. But i don't know how to find the right one for `node.js` or `java`. I found a lot of libraries that use rdf data and sparql query language but i don't get how to connect them with the .nt files.

Can anyone give a short introduction on where to start to setup the knowledge base for i.e. node.js ?

Comment: This is probably off-topic for Stack Overflow, as **"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."**  You might have a look at answers.semanticweb.com;  there might be something there, and this question would be a bit more on-topic there (library requests are more on-topic there).

Comment: If you know which system you want to use (e.g., Virtuoso, Jena (Fuseki & TDB), etc.) and have started to do this, then specific technical questions would be more answerable (and some questions around here have answers that touch on those kind of setup procedures).